# how to read variables of different name with loop in python and perform operations

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have 5 variables which are array of float 64 type in python. The name of the variables are T_1,
T_2, T_3, T_4, T_5, T_6.
Now I am running a loop, for eg.

```
for run in range(1,6):
     Tr = T_%d
```

In the above loop I want to read the 5 variables and want to perform operation. So how to read those variables as Tr = T_%d as T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4, T_5 in each loop. In each loop Tr should be of array float 64 type.

Another sample is shown below what I want to do

```
Tr_data_f5= Dataset[332,4]

for run in range (1,6):
    Tr_data = 'Tr_data_f{run}'.format(run=run)
```

Now how to read the variable Tr_data_f5 as Tr_data in the loop. With help of the above code it is getting read as string.

Comment: Make an array *of* your `T`s.

Comment: You *literally* tagged `list`. That means you must know what `list`s are, or have heard about them so you can look it up on a search engine.

Comment: In matlab we can easily perform this operation using sprintf function. so is there any such way in python

Comment: @imrankhan yes, we have `eval` in Python which can do the thing. However, you need to make many wrong turns to end up even considering it; list suggestion on top is the way to go

Comment: ok I can go with the list. I had kept that as the last option.